# Remove certain words from a string

Tags: c#

hello i am using GetDirectory to get the directory for my program. Is there a way to split the following? AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debugs\ is fixed.

```
C:\User\zhenhui\Desktop\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\
```

I want C:\User\zhenhui\Desktop\

```
C:\Users\zhenhui\Downloads\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\
```

I want C:\Users\zhenhui\Downloads\

```
C:\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\
```

I want C:\

```
D:\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\
```

I want D:\

```
E:\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\
```

I want E:\

Comment: Have you looked at regex or string.Split() ?

Comment: You could also use string.replace to replace your fixed string with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

```
directory.substring(0, directory.indexOf("AGM\\Program\\Python1\\bin\\Debugs\"))
```

Comment: Almost. You want the `substring(0, indexOf())` overload. Now you'll just return "AGM\\etc".

Comment: You probably want to do `int pos = directory.IndexOf(...);` followed by `directory.Substring(...)` if `pos != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string directory = "C:\Users\zhenhui\Downloads\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\; //your path
int index = directory.indexOf("AGM");

string outString = directory.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment since you are trying to remove a fixed portion of your path you could use the [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This is a simple Console Program to demonstrate, I created a Method to return the trimmed value, if it is used in an application that is a non console app you will need to remove the static operator.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(getProgramRootDirectory(@"C:\User\zhenhui\Desktop\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\"));
            Console.WriteLine(getProgramRootDirectory(@"C:\Users\zhenhui\Downloads\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\"));
            Console.WriteLine(getProgramRootDirectory(@"C:\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\"));
            Console.WriteLine(getProgramRootDirectory(@"D:\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\"));
            Console.WriteLine(getProgramRootDirectory(@"E:\AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\"));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static private string getProgramRootDirectory(string path)
        {
            return path.Replace(@"AGM\Program\Python1\bin\Debug\", "");
        }
    }
}
```